# CSS rounded corners bug in Safari?

Tags: css, webkit, rounded-corners

It seems that the CSS -rounded corners style works on some parts of my Stackexchange site(s) - [SF Answers](http://sfanswers.com) & [Phonehow.com](http://http:/Phonehow.com) and not on others - It displays correctly in Chrome, but not in Safari.. Im not sure if this is a Safari bug, or something I am missing. The nav bar uses the rounded corners style in all browsers, but the tabs (active,featured, hot, week, month)  are still square in Safari.  I had few of my fellow coders check it out, and they are stuck, so I thought I would ask the question here.  Thanks

Here is my code:

```
#tabs a.youarehere, #tabs a:hover, .jtabs .tabsul li:hover, .jtabs .tabsul li.ui-tabs-selected {
-moz-background-clip:border;
-moz-background-inline-policy:continuous;
-moz-background-origin:padding;
background:#FFFFFF none repeat scroll 0 0;
border-color:#BBBBBB #BBBBBB #FFFFFF;
border-style:solid;
border-width:1px;
color:#264a6f;
-moz-border-radius:4px 4px 0 0;
-webkit-border-radius:4px 4px 0 0;
```

Comment: thanks for adding the link Patrick

Comment: Nice looking sites! And please repair the link for Phonehow.com. By the way, scrolling is slow (lagging behind) in Chrome on Windows XP (but not in Safari or other browsers).

Comment: I did not do that, Patrick did.  Every time I try to change it, it says you can only add one link..vote me up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use **one value** when using `-webkit-border-radius`. It appears that Chrome can handle more values at the moment, but Safari can't. See [this post](http://www.bloggingcss.com/en/tutorials/the-css3-border-radius-property/) for a good explanation or have a look at [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS:-moz-border-radius#Browser_compatibility) (hmm, it doesn't mention Chrome). Strangely enough I couldn't find something about this on webkit.org, but I only did a quick search.

Use the [long form properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-border-radius-topleft#Examples) instead for Safari (i.e. `-webkit-border-top-left-radius` et al.).