# CSS Rounded Corners Not Working in Safari/Opera

Tags: css

I am new at CSS but am trying to learn front-end coding. I've searched a lot of different sites including this one to try and find why my rounded corners aren't working in Safari or Opera. My code already included most of what was suggested, and other's didn't seem to apply to my situation. I'm on a Mac (10.6.8). Works fine in Mozilla, IE9 & Chrome. It's a conatiner DIV that holds a swf. Here is the code:

```
#container {
  height: 600px;
  width: 955px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 18px;
  border-top-left-radius: 18px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 18px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 18px;
  -o-border-bottom-right-radius: 18px;
  -o-border-top-left-radius: 18px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 18px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 18px;
}
```

Here's a link to my site: www.mentalwarddesign.net

I've also tried (for the heck of it) indicating "0" values on the 2 corners I don't want affected. In addition I've tried "border-radius: 18px" to simply round all corners. Both with the same effect of working in all but Safari & Opera (well, IE 6-8 too of course). It must be something simple. If I've missed this question answered here before, please forgive me and point me in the right direction. The closest post I found here was this one: [CSS rounded corners bug in Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224386/css-rounded-corners-bug-in-safari) but I didn't find anything helpful there.

Comment: Put your non-vendor specific declarations after the vendor-prefixed versions.

Comment: Or don't bother with vendor specific declarations as all modern browsers now support `border-radius`

Comment: @kinakuta & @ Michael Irogoyen. Thank you for the tips. I've reordered the declarations, but kept the vendor-specific ones for older versions. Still however not displaying correctly in Saf/Opera.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find working version with code...

http://www.css3maker.com/

http://css3please.com/

Comment: It seems my CSS code for the radius is correct, but my problem lies elsewhere. Thanks for the links, they look like great resources!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's actually a case of the flash player not complying with `overflow: hidden`. Presumably, it works with text in place of the swf?

IIRC, you have to add a `wmode` `<param />` to the swf:

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
```

Comment: I just tested it with text and a solid background in place of the swf, and yes you are correct. Thanks for your help. Being new to this it's nice to know I did the right thing, but a little frustrating that I can't get what I want. Is there any work-around?

Comment: Oh, I guess that's what you're indicating with <param/>. Thanks again I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @Ed: If it works, make sure to click the tick next to my answer.

Comment: Yeah, doesn't seem to work. Went back to the Flash doc & published that with transparent windows too & reinserted the swf (I'm using Dreamweaver). and changed the wmode value to transparent. It's something I can live with, and I do appreciate your help. Thanks.