# Safari 6 Round Corners Glitch

Tags: safari, css

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSvEf.png]

Hi! As you can see on the image, there's a strange behaviour in safari 6 with round corners

```
{ border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px; }
```

when hovering over the elements there is a thin line that's building up when hovering more and more times... The first and second link wasn't hovered over, and you can see different lines caused by hovering mouse over the elements a few times...

Is that just a bug in safari?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could send us a link so we can try ourself. Maybe it isn't online? Well try jsfiddle.net then.

Comment: On the face of it, I am quite sure this is something to do with your code and not a Safari issue. Example would help here.

Comment: The site is online now: http://firma-admiral.pl/

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this exact behavior before, but I've seen similar. I assume you are on a Retina MBP? and certainly on Mountain Lion. Safari *is* occasionally having issues with border-radius and virtual resolution (which is how the retina display works).

Try quitting safari, changing your resolution, and opening it again. If it looks better at first, then you'll just have to wait for a fix from Apple.

In the meantime, you might have some luck making sure all border styles make it hidden:

```
border-color: transparent;
border-style: none;
border-width: 0;
```

Hope that helps!

-Mike

Comment: Tried the code you provided but with no luck... I'm on a MBP 13" 2012. My gf is on a MBP 13" Late 2011, we're both on Mountain Lion so the issue is not with the graphic cards... I guess we wait for the update... Chrome works good, Firefox and even IE is ok ;]

Comment: Sorry to hear that... Last shot in the dark, though: any chance it's the css `outline` style? Maybe try `outline: transparent none 0 !important;`?

Answer (score 0):

This post may answer your question [CSS rounded corners bug in Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224386/css-rounded-corners-bug-in-safari).

Try to use:

```
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
```

instead of:

```
border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
```