# Transparent rounded border in Safari

Tags: safari, css, rgba

When using an alpha transparency border with rounded corners in Safari, the background clips into the border. This happens even when using background-clip: padding-box. I know that I can simply wrap the h1's in a span/div/etc and give that the border, but I'm wondering if anyone knows if it is possible to do this without any more mark up.

Here is the css I'm using:

```
    h1.inner {
    background: #ffa51f;
    border-top-right-radius: 60px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 60px;
    border-top: 10px solid rgba(33,33,33,.05);
    border-bottom: 10px solid rgba(33,33,33,.05);
    border-right: 10px solid rgba(33,33,33,.05);
    color: #FFF;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 47px;
    font-weight: 800;
    line-height: 1.2;
    padding: 0 .6em 0 0;
    position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: left;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1.inner:before {
    background: #ffa51f;
    border-top: 10px solid rgba(33,33,33,.05);
    border-bottom: 10px solid rgba(33,33,33,.05);
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    bottom: -10px;
    width: 9999px;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1.inner:before {
    right: 100%;
}
```

Below is a jsfiddle and screenshot with an example of what I'm talking about.

http://jsfiddle.net/39Xen/

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfS8l.jpg

Comment: what version of safari?

Comment: As near as I can tell, it used to be a [webkit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23166). I'm guessing that you're testing Safari on Windows? If that's the case, then Apple stopped supporting Safari on Windows, so it won't be fixed.

Comment: This is on OSX, with the latest version of Safari.

Comment: Why are you using a :before for such a simply effect?

Comment: I have the entire website in a wrapper that centers everything. Using the before and after pseudo elements allows me to easily have full page width divs regardless of screen size.

Answer (score 0):

Is it posible that what you are asking has been addressed here:
[CSS rounded corners bug in Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224386/css-rounded-corners-bug-in-safari)
?
It seems that Safari has some limitation with respect to what you are trying to do.
Hope that helps.